how to remove recaptcha screen from phone authentication of flutter app firebase.(2024)
in my app i am using firebase for phone authetication, when user enter the phone number it run a "i am not robot page" next it going to the otp enter page and send the code. i want to stop the i am not robot page.
in my app i am using firebase for phone authetication, when user enter the phone number it run a "i am not robot page" next it going to the otp enter page and send the code. i want to stop the i am not robot page.

You have to Just add SHA-1 & SHA-256 Keys in your Firebase project.
You can add key using below steps:
step 1: open terminal of IDE
step 2: cd android
step 3: ./gradlew signingReport
Here you will get sha1 and sha-256 which you can add in your firebase project.
